Limiting factors in traditional microscopy
I have been researching Entanglement-Enhanced Microscopy, and the overall breakthrough seems to be obtaining a resolution of $1/N$ as opposed to $1/\sqrt N$. This led me to ask what the limiting factors in traditional microscopy are that keep it from reaching a $1/N$ resolution.

In unentangled microscopy there are no entanglement correlations among the detected photons but photon detections are quantised and this gives their detections Poissonian statistics with fluctuations of the photon number above and below the mean value of $\sqrt{N}$ which is what causes the resolution of $1/\sqrt{N}$ for standard microscopy, see Chapter 5 of "Quantum Optics: An Introduction" by Mark Fox and for a review of more general quantum interferometry see
https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.7703

Thank you; this helps a lot! Could you please point me where I can calculate this relation to prove it mathematically?

Chapter 5 of "Quantum Optics: An Introduction" by Mark Fox

I'm sorry for the misunderstanding, but I meant to find the classical interpretation to compare the two quantitatively.

The explanation for the $1/\sqrt{N}$ comes from the Poisson statistics as I explained above and as explained in the reference I gave. There is no classical explanation for this because there is no such thing as a photon in classical electromagnetism.
